# How to put .wav file in avi file in matlab 2010a

Tags: matlab, audio

I am running the following code in matlab 2010a:

```
data=wavread('audiofile.wav'); 
writerObj = video.MultimediaFileWriter(aviobj,'AudioInputPort',true,'FileFormat','WAV');

val = size(data,1)/numFrames; 
for k = 1:numFrames % % reading frames from a directory 
    Frame=(imread(strcat('Nyk',num2str(k),'.png'))); % % adding the audio variable in the step function 
    step(writerObj,Frame,data(val*(k-1)+1:valk,:)); % it is 2 channel that is why I have put (:) 
    step(writerObj,Frame,data(val(k-1)+1:val*k)); 
end

% release the video

release(writerObj)
```

But it gives the errors below:

> ??? Error using ==> compSetParameters Reported by
>   video.MultimediaFileWriter: The Filename property value must be a
>   non-empty string.
>
> Error in ==> C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\dspblks\dspblks+signalblks+private\MultimediaFileWriterBase.p>MultimediaFileWriterBase.setParameters
>   at 121
>
> Error in ==> audiomerge at 27
>   step(writerObj,Frame,data(val*(k-1)+1:val*k,:)); % it is 2 channel
>   that is why I have put (:)

Any hints where the problem is?

Comment: correction in the above code                                            step(writerObj,Frame,data(val*(k-1)+1:valk,:));                                                    % it is 2 channel that is why I have put (:)                                                                                                           %the line after the above line is commented                                                         end

Comment: I'd suggest using actual video editing software for this sort of operation, e.g., ffmpeg, QuickTime Pro, iMovie, Adobe Premiere, etc.

Comment: I agree with horchler.  Don't use MATLAB for this when professional software is designed to do this for you.